# How to export scenes with many materials for one mesh

Tags: export

Suppose I have this scene with some cubes sharing the same mesh but assigned different materials per object. And I would like to import this scene into unreal using fbx

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Unreal generates a static mesh for each cube. Is there any way to make unreal import only one static mesh and assign different materials for each instance of it in the imported scene?

Comment: This is more of an UE5 question than a Blender question. I'm not sure about where to find this option in UE5, but in the UE4 static mesh import dialog there's a [checkbox](https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/unwanted-combining-of-meshes-on-import-of-fbx/310866/2) called "Combine Meshes" that I think is what you're looking for.

Comment: Or you could use an object info node's random output attached with a colour ramp to get the different colours...